# improving isearch

Tags: isearch

1. I wonder if I can disable the 'failing overwrapped' warning in the minibuffer and directly wrap around instead if I do a search?

Does anyone know how to facilitate this?

2. Also there is a slight delay in highlighting occurrences of the search-for expression, can I decrease this as well?
3. Finally, how can I invoke custom function upon a key combination, only if Isearch is active?

Specifically, I want to invoke

```
  (defun contrib/isearchp-remove-failed-part-or-last-char ()
    "Remove failed part of search string, or last char if successful.
Do nothing if search string is empty to start with."
    (interactive)
    (if (equal isearch-string "")
        (isearch-update)
      (if isearch-success
          (isearch-delete-char)
        (while (isearch-fail-pos) (isearch-pop-state)))
      (isearch-update)))
```

if I hit `<backspace>` during Isearch.

Comment: You asked three questions here: (1) how to *"disable 'failing overwrapped'", directly wrapping, (2) how to reduce the delay, and (3) *"how can I invoke..."*. Please remove two of them - move them to separate questions. Thx.

Comment: And after removing 2 of the questions, please edit the question title, to make it specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For quick direction change and wrap around you can use the following:

```
(defun isearch-repeat-forward+ ()
  (interactive)
  (unless isearch-forward
    (goto-char isearch-other-end))
  (isearch-repeat-forward)
  (unless isearch-success
    (isearch-repeat-forward)))

(defun isearch-repeat-backward+ ()
  (interactive)
  (when (and isearch-forward isearch-other-end)
    (goto-char isearch-other-end))
  (isearch-repeat-backward)
  (unless isearch-success
    (isearch-repeat-backward)))


(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-repeat-forward+)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-r") 'isearch-repeat-backward+)
```

By binding the keys in `isearch-mode-map` those bindings are only used when isearch is active, you can do the same with your `contrib/isearchp-remove-failed-part-or-last-char` command.

As for the delay question, you need to search for the variable for this setting. You can use `apropos-user-option`, `apropos-documentation` or just `describe-variable` (+ maybe using a completion framework of your choice) to find `isearch-lazy-highlight-initial-delay` which is obsoleted by `lazy-highlight-initial-delay` (as you can read in the docstring).